# Where should I set the flag to false again?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Follow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform targetToFollow;
    public Text text;
    public float lookAtRotationSpeed;
    public float moveSpeed;

    private float minMoveSpeed = 0f;
    private bool moveInDistance = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 lTargetDir = targetToFollow.position - transform.position;
        lTargetDir.y = 0.0f;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation,
            Quaternion.LookRotation(lTargetDir), Time.time * lookAtRotationSpeed);

        var distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetToFollow.position);

        text.text = distance.ToString();

        if(distance > 5f && moveInDistance == false)
        {
            moveSpeed = moveSpeed + 0.5f * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (distance > 1.5f && distance < 5f)
        {
            moveInDistance = true;
            moveSpeed = moveSpeed + 0.05f;
        }
        else if (distance < 1f)
        {
            moveSpeed = Mathf.Max(minMoveSpeed, moveSpeed - 0.3f);
        }

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetToFollow.position, Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
    }
}
```

The first time the game is running the transform will move faster to the target in this part :

```
if(distance > 5f && moveInDistance == false)
            {
                moveSpeed = moveSpeed + 0.5f * Time.deltaTime;
            }
```

Then when the transform has reach close distance to the target he will keep following the target in slower speed in this part :

```
if (distance > 1.5f && distance < 5f)
            {
                moveInDistance = true;
                moveSpeed = moveSpeed + 0.05f;
            }
```

The problem is if in the future in the game I will want to change the speed again if the transform will be more then 5 distance from the target. Then where should I change the flag moveInDistance to false again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put moveInDistance before moving logical like

```
moveInDistance = distance > 1.5f && distance < 5f; // or other condition

if(distance > 5f && !moveInDistance)
{
    moveSpeed = moveSpeed + 0.5f * Time.deltaTime;
}
if (distance > 1.5f && distance < 5f)
{
    moveSpeed = moveSpeed + 0.05f;
}
else if (distance < 1f)
{
    moveSpeed = Mathf.Max(minMoveSpeed, moveSpeed - 0.3f);
}
...
```

Add example if else for comment

```
...

float ms = moveSpeed;

if(distance > 5f)
{
    ms = moveSpeed + 0.5f; //move faster
}
else if (distance < 1f)
{
    ms = Mathf.Max(minMoveSpeed, moveSpeed - 0.3f); // move slower
}else {
    //set your ms (movement speed) when follwer is move in distance range if you don’t need default value that equal moveSpeed here
}

// by default if distance in range of 1-5 ms is equal moveSpeed and IsInRange Case

// move object by using ms value
...
```

Ps. In my opinion I think moveInDistance is not important thing to use in my if-else condition you can check distance range in elseIf statement instead of set to moveInDistance

Comment: I want to do the same logic as in game for example when a man have his dog following him. If the dog is too far the dog should run faster to catch up the man but if the dog is close to the man then now just walk "beside" the man. And then again if in some case in the game the dog is too far the dog should increase the speed to catch up the man and then again walk "beside" or follow the man slowly.

Comment: The problem here is that when running the game first time and the distance is more then 5 then both conditions will exist and the transform will hit the target because it will increase the speed in both conditions.

Comment: First you can declare **ms** variable in fixupdate scope and set constant speed in each condition instead of modify **moveSpeed** value so your moveSpeed is consistency.

Comment: Second, you can set if else condition like ny edit example

Answer (score 0):

You could edit your existing `if statement` alittle to include what you are after:

```
if(distance > 5f)
{
  if (moveInDistance == false) {
    moveSpeed = moveSpeed + 0.5f * Time.deltaTime;
  } else {
    moveInDistance = false;
  }
}
```